# Broadcast using Pub-Sub in multiple node instances

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I want to have 2 instances of the node server 'A' and 'B'.

'A' will push connected clients [socket.io is used] in a room.

'A' will publish an event to which 'B' is already subscribed.

On receiving that particular event from 'A', instance 'B' will broadcast a message in the given room. Want to use the Room feature of socket.io

Want to ask that, is it possible ? 
I am trying redis store, but not getting how to publish an event so that server 'B' will receive it.

Comment: refer to the answer given [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396252/sharing-io-object-in-multiple-node-instances/20467890#20467890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run 2 instances of redis, one on server A and one on server B.

if you bind adresses on A to * or to 127.0.0.1,B's IP, you can ask the server B to be slave of A: `slaveof <A ip adress> 6379`

every publish made by A will be replicate To B , so you can listen on the B serveur to the channel and push that you want to the Room

For you information , you can start the server to test like this :
On A :

```
redis-server --port 6391 --bind (B-IP) --bind 127.0.0.1
```

on B:

```
redis-server --port 6392 --slaveof (A-IP) 6391
```

i'm not fully tested this solution(only tested on local host for the twice server) , but that should work

if you want to take care of some keys you can use psubscribe with some "keys" as channel name. i done it like that before:

on A

```
publish "|key1=toto||key2=titi||key3=plop|" "nanana"
```

on B

```
PSUBSCRIBE "*|key2=titi|*"
```

as you see separator on the key , you will have only the filtering push

you can do something like that in your node/socketIo :
on A

```
var redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();
client.publish("room::"+roomID, message);
```

on B

```
var redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();
client.on("pmessage", function (pattern,channel, message){
    //emit on roomid(in channel) the message
}
client.psubscribe("room::*");
```

not tested...

Comment: thanks for the reply, If i want to run node instances on same server then in that case, redis client in process A and redis client in process B should talk to each other, right ? And is redis-store helpful in anycase ?

Comment: it's more easy/secure to run them on same server , the bind adress is on 127.0.0.1 so safer. everything happenind on A  is replicate on B pub/sub, key,list, etc....  I'm very fan of redis because is fast and persistable with some pub/sub inside and scripting in lua also . a lot of design is possible some use of case here :http://redis.io/documentation

Comment: roger that, trying that now

Comment: thanks, slave is receiving master's events. Now need to implement this through node.

Comment: may be this https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/ . Redis protocol is very simple

Comment: just a quick question, how can I access room members created by instance A, I want to broadcast in the room from instance B ?

Comment: Plus, can you please suggest if my thinking is correct or not - let clients get in the room at instance A and clients will receive messages from instance B. instance A will be performing major other tasks hence some tasks need to be delegated.

Comment: everything is replicated from A to B, store the list of room in A they will be in B. if A just publish message and store un list, it will be not so hard for him. if B will be out of subscribing (it's inscreasing by number of message and subscribe) you can multiply B instance and distribute subscribing on them. not sure i'm well understanding your needs

Comment: almost there, but not getting how should i access io.sockets.in('roomID').emit(...) in instance B, thats the exact problem.. thank you so much for all

Comment: you can start by trying to publish on A the message on a channel named roomID and on B subscribe on * and opn message income do a  io.sockets.in(channel).emit(message) look at https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/#publish--subscribe . i put it on the main answer

Comment: //emit on roomid(in channel) the message, how to do that, was the original question, sorry to bother you again but I am not getting access to sockets in redis via io.sockets.in(..) in instance B :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42575/discussion-between-philippe-t-and-pranav)