# sharing IO object in multiple node instances

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I want to share rooms created by socket.io between two node instances, already using redis-store but unable to get io.sockets.in(ROOM_ID).emit(MESSAGE,DATA) on different node instance;

I am trying - 
instance A -

```
io.set('store',...)

io.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.join(''room-ABCD);
});
```

to broadcst something, I am able to use

```
io.sockets.in('room-ABCD').emit('event',{data:{}});
```

but similar broadcast I need to perform from instance B.

on instance B `io.set('store')` is similar to above, but I am not able to use `io.sockets.in('room-ABCD').emit('event',{data:{}})`

My understanding is - redisStore will put socket+room information in redis so that it is accessible to other process.[please correct if I am wrong].
now, I am not getting how to identify and fetch this information in other process of node.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the queries related to the questions - [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375338/broadcast-using-pub-sub-in-multiple-node-instances),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464490/how-redis-store-stores-room-data-in-redis) and this one.

Exact point where I need to concentrte was - Joinig the room.

I was using `client_socket.join("room_name")`, but it pushes the client socket to the room.

Now, try `io.sockets.socket(client_socket.id).join("room_name")`.

This pushes the room members to the redis and now they are accessible in another node instance.

in process B `io.sockets.in("room_name").emit("event_name",{data:"1"})` works.

Answer (score 0):

If i good understanding your problem. youre start point was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375338/broadcast-using-pub-sub-in-multiple-node-instances/20375644?noredirect=1#comment30449836_20375644)
You can probably access to A from B (host not redis). So in A you can push that's you need to emit on A:

```
LPUSH dataToEmit "{'room':'room-ABCD', 'data':'<escapeddata>'}"
```

and on your A process you perform a BRPOP on dataToEmit and on the callback you can unjsonize and emit that you want

may be you could also dispatch to 1 key for 1 room . Don't forget that's you can use a specific data base number for this stuff

I Hope that's migth help you