# How redis-store stores room data in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

When a client joins a room, all corresponding data (i.e rooms, sockets in rooms and other) goes to Redis.
I need to understand where it is stored in red and how to fetch it.

Because I need to fetch it in another process. Means, I will be starting another node instance and then I will access room clients to broadcast something.

I am using redis-store.

Comment: refer to the answer given [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396252/sharing-io-object-in-multiple-node-instances/20467890#20467890

Comment: do you want an example of data-distributing  in different type of key? or how redis work?

Comment: would like to read about it more, but for now i am able to achieve whatever i mentioned above and other related questions. Redis-store allows to read room clients from another process also. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

While redis is an in-memory storage system. So that data is stored in your computer's memory. As to how to access it you can interact with redis through its command line interface. [redis info](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart)

Not entirely sure what you mean by fetch it in another process. Are you talking about another node-js instance or a different program? [list of redis clients](http://redis.io/clients)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have edited the question's second para. I will use another node instance to access rooms created in first instance.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have to store data in different key. you may be store list of room in a set and other stuff in a hash. Because of the key/value design you may have to cut data in several keys.All type is designed for a use. You can store that you want in atomic "box", json for example

- Simple string is the atomic way of storing , and provide also expireat/persist system.
- list provide you queuing and slicing system
- set is an uniquify list
- sorted set a a scoring system , so you can slice and select by an other value
- hash is a array of string

in each smallest part of type you can store that you want , a json for exemple.
If you have structured information you may want o use a hash (key could be your roomId, for exemple). This hash could be the place where your store really your data. But you may have other key to provide a indexing system. for exemple you can have a key that's provide you to have , for a client id , the rooms id, etc....  you migth have to select your data in two times, selecting keys by a handmade index , and select data from the keys

you can make transaction and multiple command . You can also script in Lua . And You can use pub/sub system, that's is quite use full

you want that your other program is aware of change and broadcast them? no problem. Store informations in each places and publish a update event . Other programs subscribe to modification and reload information, and to something with.